# python regular expression does not return the value as expected

Tags: python

I only need to print out the non-match item which "333-33". When I run the following code, it prints all the items such as "111-11", "222-22", "333-33"...

"333-33" should return the None type...

Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance.

```
ALLOW_LIST = ["(4[0-4]{2})-\d{2}", "111-11", "222-22"]

item=[]

codes = ["111-11", "222-22", "333-33"]
for code in codes:
    for i in ALLOW_LIST:
        if re.search(i, code) is None:
            item.append(code)
print(item)
```

Comment: The way you've written your regex, it is supposed to pick a `4` followed by two same digits between `0` and `4`, followed by a dash and finally followed by two digits - none of your codes would be captured by that. The rest are just straight matches, not really patterns. Then you're checking if any of your codes doesn't match any of the patterns in `ALLOW_LIST` which is true for all of them at one point so no wonder you end up with all of them in your `item` list. You should probably rethink the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `re.search()` is returning `None` as expected when matching against the three regex patterns in `ALLOW_LIST`, and when that happens you're appending the `code` to `item`, when you seem to want to be appending `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `all` function with a generator expression that iterates through `ALLOW_LIST` to ensure that none of the patterns matches the current `code` before outputting it:

```
[code for code in codes if all(not re.search(i, code) for i in ALLOW_LIST)]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to include only items matched by allow list.

Your if statement will append items that are **not matched**: `if re.search(i, code) is None:`

You should edit out your if statement to include items that are matched:

```
ALLOW_LIST = ["(4[0-4]{2})-\d{2}", "111-11", "222-22"]

item=[]

codes = ["111-11", "222-22", "333-33"]
for code in codes:
    for i in ALLOW_LIST:
        if re.search(i, code):
            item.append(code)
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could form a single regex alternation here:

```py
ALLOW_LIST = ["4[0-4]{2}-\d{2}", "111-11", "222-22"]
regex = r'^(?:' + '|'.join(ALLOW_LIST) + r')$'

items = []
codes = ["111-11", "222-22", "333-33"]
for code in codes:
    if not re.search(regex, code):
        items.append(code)

print(items)  # ['333-33']
```